# Mercurial: Pulling in others merges + branching

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, branching-and-merging

I'm still very new to Mercurial so please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

We have an hg repo for each of our developers. I'm working on a new feature in branch `x`. Since then, others have made critical changes to the project, which I have pulled into my repo. However, when I'm working on branch `x` my working copy still has the old stuff, which causes it to not play well w/ our shared MySQL database.

Q: How do I update my branch to have the other developers new stuff while keeping my own code in the `x` branch; I'm not ready for them to have it yet and I definitely don't want to merge `x` into `default`... I'm not sure what to do here...

Or am I going about this the entirely wrong way? If so, what should I be doing instead?

[edit]
Also, I'm using TortoiseHG, so if you have any instructions specific for that it would be appreciated.
[/edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing everything right. In order to "keep up" with the work of the other developers, you have to merge the default branch into your `x` branch. Not the other way around.

When you are in your `x` branch, it is as easy as doing `hg merge default`.

**Edit** : I deleted my statement about `hg merge` being equivalent to `hg merge default`, which is false. I misread the documentation.

Comment: Is there a difference between `[default] $ hg merge x` and `[x] $ hg merge default`?

Comment: Yes, the main difference is that the newly created changeset will belong to the `default` branch in the former case, and to the `x` branch in the latter.